# Limit related to $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I was looking at limits involving $\sin x$ and was wondering if there exists a function $f(x)$ such that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(\frac{a}{x})}=b,
$$

where $$b \ne 0$$
$$\frac{df(x)}{da}=0$$
and
$$\frac{db}{da}=0$$

In other words, is it possible for this to converge to a nonzero value that does not involve $a$ while also keeping $f(x)$ from involving $a$. Because one can do

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sin(\frac{a}{x})}=\frac{1}{a},
$$
or 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{a}{x}}{\sin(\frac{a}{x})}=1,$$

but $a$ has to appear either in $f$ or in the result. Is there a function where this doesn't happen?
Also, it seems to me that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sin(\frac{a}{x})}=0,$$

and the only way to make this converge is to bring it to zero? Decided to ask because I could be missing some interesting limit where the above requirements are met.

Comment: The convergence of the limit of interest is equivalent to the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x f(x)=ab$$But inasmuch as $f$ and $b$ are independent of $a$, this is not possible for $b\ne 0$.